# Given the logical address, how to extract the page number?

Tags: operating-systems, memory-management, paging, virtual-memory

I am studying Computer Systems. I have th following question and its answer:

> Given the logical address 0xAEF9 (in hexadecimal) with a page size of
>   256 bytes, what is the page number?
>
> Answer: **0xAE** (I found this answer in the web, but I want to know how can I
>   figure it out myself?

How can I figure out the page number for a given logical address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logical address is made of 16 bits, that means you have a addressable space of $2^{16}$ bits. The page size is typically a power of 2, $2^n$, in this case $2^n = 256 \Rightarrow n = 8$.

The page number is calculated by substracting $n$ from the size of your logical address: $16 - 8 = 8$, so the first 8 bits of the address are your missing page number, that is 0xAE

Answer (score 0):

Logical address includes both page number and the offset within the page.
Your logical address is **16** bit.
Page size as mentioned is **256** = **2<sup>8</sup>**. It means that **8** bit address is necessary to address any word within the page.
The least significant **8** bits are used for this purpose (as offset address)

The remaining bits (the most significant **8** bits) are used as page number.

So the fist **8** bits specify the page number. **0xAE** in this case.

Comment: duplicated answer maybe

Answer (score 0):

Page Number=Logical Address/Page Size

AEF9 converted to decimal-> 1*9+16*15+16^2*14+16^3*10 = 44793

44793/256=174

174 in hexa-> AE

Comment: There is absolutely no need to convert to decimal. AE are the first two hexadecimal digits of AEF9.